# angular 2 window resize get width of immediate parent

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am reusing a component inside 4 different components. On window resize, every parent component's width will be different and I want to pass that unique width to the common child component.

I was using:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef)......

window.onresize = (e) =>{
  console.log("issues",this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement);
}
```

.....

But this gives me the last parent's width and not 4 different widths.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `width: 100%;` on the common child in css?